# Magical Records CoreData migration issue

Tags: ios, core-data, database-migration, magicalrecord

I setuped CoreData using Magical Records with line

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"MyModel"];
```

Now in phase 2 of the app I'm doing

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"MyModel 2"];
```

but what happens is that the data gets cleared. Everything starts from scratch :( I'm in deep nuisance please help. Anybody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make changes to an existing core data model you have to add a new version.

[image]

This doesn't mean that your data base name has changed, all thats happening is that you are telling Core Data that a new version has been added and thats where the auto migration magic can begin. Thats why you can open your .xcdatamodeld in finder, show package contents, and you will see your two versions.

So continue initialising Magical Record with the original model name: `[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"MyModel"];`

You should have a green tick next to MyModel.xcdatamodeld 2 in your file inspector:)

You also need to be aware that MagicalRecord will delete the model in Debug mode if it cannot perform migrations so please read the [lightweight migration guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) on how to setup valid model changes for lightweight migration

Comment: Yes Store name will never change. I was changing it. Thanks :)